# Find function with given local extrema points or inflection points?

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, optimization

I'm stuck with this kind of math problems when you have to find a function with given local extrema points or inflection points. Are there any general formula or method to find the function?

For instance, find a function with a local maximimum point at $(1, 2)$ and a local minimum point at $(5, -4)$?
How would you solve it (with derivative)?

I start with this:

$$f(1) = 2 \qquad f(5) = -4 \qquad f'(1) = 0 \qquad f'(5) = 0\\
f''(1) < 0 (\text{max point}) \\
f''(5) > 0 (\text{min point})$$

and then try to solve $$f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$$

but it doesn't work.

Comment: I think it should work with a cubic. What happens if you start by only requiring the function goes through the two given points and has derivative 0 at those points? Include your attempt. If it fails try a fourth degree...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(1)=2$ gives $a+b+c=d=2.$ And $f(5)=-4$ gives $125a+25b+5c+d=-4.$

Also $f'(1)=0$ gives $3a+2b+c=0,$ and $f'(5)=0$ gives $75a+10b+c=0.$

This is four linear equations in four unknowns. I just checked, and there is a unique solution.

And note with the values plugged in the function $f(x)$ has the required properties.

Comment: You are a life saver! :D

Comment: Note that the facts about $f''(x)$ at $x=1,5$ are just consequences to the above, since a cubic always has either no local max/mins or one, or two, and the given data forces there to be two, with the one at 1 being the local max and the one at 5 being the local min.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I solved it but I didn't really understand why it worked until you explained!

Answer (score 0):

Since it should have zero slope at $ x = 1 $ and at $ x = 5 $, we take the derivative as a quadratic

$$ k \, y^{'}(x) = ( x-1) (x-5) $$

Integrating,

$$ k y(x) = x^3/3 - 3 x^2 + 5 x + c   ...(1*) $$

To evaluate (k,c) use the given (x,y ) at  extreme pints:

$ @ x =1, y = 2 ; \Rightarrow 2 k = 7/3 + c $ ;

$ @ x =5, y =-4 ;  \Rightarrow  4 k = 25/3 - c; $

Solving, $( k,c) = ( 16/9,11/9) $ ; which should be plugged into $ (1*)$